# Firebase signOut() method or AuthListener not working as intended

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication, fragment

I have a Fragment with a signOut button in my android studio app that is supposed to log the user out of his account and then redirect him back to the login page. I've tried several things so far and looked at every thread I could find but nothing is working. There is no error, just no reaction at all.

First thing I've tried is this:

```
    public class PreferenceFragment extends Fragment {

    private PreferenceViewModel preferenceViewModel;
    private FragmentPreferenceBinding binding;
    private Button btnSignOut;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener;


    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        preferenceViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(PreferenceViewModel.class);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_preference, container, false);

        btnSignOut = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.sign_out);

        binding = FragmentPreferenceBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();

        final TextView textView = binding.textPreference;
        preferenceViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });
        authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user == null) {
                    // user auth state is changed - user is null
                    // launch login activity
                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class));
                    getActivity().finish();
                }
            }
        };

        btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                auth.signOut();
            }

        });
        return root;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        auth.addAuthStateListener(authListener);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (authListener != null) {
            auth.removeAuthStateListener(authListener);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my LoginActivity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Button btnSignup, btnLogin, btnReset;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Get Firebase auth instance
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }

        // set the view now
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        btnSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        btnReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reset_password);

        //Get Firebase auth instance
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        btnSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignupActivity.class));
            }
        });

        btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ResetPasswordActivity.class));
            }
        });

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                final String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                //authenticate user
                auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                                // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                                // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    // there was an error
                                    if (password.length() < 6) {
                                        inputPassword.setError(getString(R.string.minimum_password));
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.auth_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

First I thought it might be the signOut() that isn't working as intended or logging me back in automatically. But if I put the signOut() into the onStop() method of the MainActivity it is working, obviously only when I close the app:

```
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
    }
```

then I thought the program might not be calling the same FirebasAuth instance so I've tried calling the FirebaseAuth instance from the MainActivity to the same effect:

```
(MainActivity)getActivity()).auth.signOut();
```

I've tried several other things like putting the authListener in the MainActivity or removing the code calling the FirebasAuth instance at the start of the LoginActivity, always to the same effect. Maybe it has to do with my startActivity but I'm not sure how to do it differently. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If you are interested in using a clean Firebase authentication, then I recommend you read the following article, [How to create a clean Firebase authentication using MVVM?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336).

Comment: I did read it and have updated my project in a similar way. The problem seems to be with the button in my fragment. I've tried debugging it and it seems like my signout button never actually performs the action specified, in my case calling the signOut method from main. It just gets stuck in a loop and then just stops.

Comment: Make sure your button is fully functional.